# Keep animation (keyframes) state, when removed reverse with same animation to origin state

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I got an animation that I keep the state with `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`. I would like for it to animate the same way back to it's origin once the class for it is removed. How would I do that?

This is what I got

```js
document.querySelector(".js-toggle-animation").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle("container--is-active");
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 20rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: crimson;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container__toggle-action {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}

.container__content {
  position: relative;
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: lighten(crimson, 20%);
}

.information-block {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 60%;
  padding: 1.875rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 3;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

.container--is-active .information-block {
  animation: smooth-in 320ms ease forwards;
}

@keyframes smooth-in {
  10% {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-right: calc(1.875rem);
    padding-left: calc(1.875rem);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  70% {
    bottom: -2rem;
    height: calc(60% + 4rem);
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-right: calc(1.875rem);
    padding-left: calc(1.875rem);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    bottom: -2rem;
    height: calc(60% + 4rem);
    margin-right: -2rem;
    margin-left: -2rem;
    padding-right: calc(1.875rem + 2rem);
    padding-left: calc(1.875rem + 2rem);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="container__toggle-action js-toggle-animation">toggle animation</button>

  <div class="container__content">
    <div class="information-block">
      <h2>headline</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque obcaecati debitis nihil ratione dicta quaerat, dolores quis laboriosam quae recusandae!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see i add a reverse animation, so when you press the second time div will disappear

```js
document.querySelector(".js-toggle-animation").addEventListener("click", () => {
  if( document.querySelector(".container").classList.contains('container--is-active')){
  document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle("container--is-not-active");
  document.querySelector(".container").classList.remove("container--is-active");
  }else if( document.querySelector(".container").classList.contains('container--is-not-active')){
  document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle("container--is-active");
  document.querySelector(".container").classList.remove("container--is-not-active");
  }else{
  document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle("container--is-active");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: crimson;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container__toggle-action {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}

.container__content {
  position: relative;
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: lighten(crimson, 20%);
}

.information-block {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 60%;
  padding: 1.875rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 3;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

.container--is-active .information-block {
  animation: smooth-in 320ms ease forwards;
}
.container--is-not-active .information-block {
  animation: smooth-in-reverse 320ms ease forwards;
}

@keyframes smooth-in {
  10% {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-right: calc(1.875rem);
    padding-left: calc(1.875rem);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  70% {
    bottom: -2rem;
    height: calc(60% + 4rem);
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-right: calc(1.875rem);
    padding-left: calc(1.875rem);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    bottom: -2rem;
    height: calc(60% + 4rem);
    margin-right: -2rem;
    margin-left: -2rem;
    padding-right: calc(1.875rem + 2rem);
    padding-left: calc(1.875rem + 2rem);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  }
  @keyframes smooth-in-reverse {
  10% {
    bottom: -2rem;
    height: calc(60% + 4rem);
    margin-right: -2rem;
    margin-left: -2rem;
    padding-right: calc(1.875rem + 2rem);
    padding-left: calc(1.875rem + 2rem);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  70% {
    bottom: -2rem;
    height: calc(60% + 4rem);
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-right: calc(1.875rem);
    padding-left: calc(1.875rem);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-right: calc(1.875rem);
    padding-left: calc(1.875rem);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: none;
   
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="container__toggle-action js-toggle-animation">toggle animation</button>

  <div class="container__content">
    <div class="information-block">
      <h2>headline</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eaque obcaecati debitis nihil ratione dicta quaerat, dolores quis laboriosam quae recusandae!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It feels a bit messy with having to add a to add a class when removing the item. Is there another way?

Comment: i think is the only way. another very similar solution would be to change the button to render one class rather than the other

Comment: have you find another way?